# What is the inverse of $"P \mbox{ implies } (Q \mbox{ or } R)”$?

Tags: logic

What is the inverse of "$P \mbox{ implies} (Q \mbox{ or } R)$". 
I remember it to if not (Q or R) then not P.

Does this mean that that both Q and R have to be false for P to be false?

Comment: By inverse, you mean negation ?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "*inverse*" ?

---

The **contrapositive** of $\;P\to (Q\vee R)\;$ is $\;(\neg Q\wedge \neg R)\to \neg P\;$.

If $P$ is true, then either $Q$ or $R$ are true.   If both $Q$ and $R$ are false, then $P$ is false.   These statements are *equivalent*.

---

The **negation** of $\;P\to (Q\vee R)\;$ is $\;P\wedge (\neg Q\wedge \neg R)$.

If $P$ is true, then either $Q$ or $R$ are true.   $P$ is true and both $Q$ and $R$ are false.   These statements *contradict* each other.

$$\begin{array}{c:c:c|c:c|c} P & Q & R & P\to(Q\vee R) & (\neg Q \wedge \neg R)\to P & P \wedge (\neg Q\wedge \neg R) \\ \hline T & T & T & T & T & \color{navy}{F} \\ T & T & \color{navy}{F} & T & T & \color{navy}{F} \\ T & \color{navy}{F} & T & T & T & \color{navy}{F}\\[1ex] T & \color{navy}{F} & \color{navy}{F} & \color{navy}{F} & \color{navy}{F} & T \\[1ex] \color{navy}{F} & T & T & T & T & \color{navy}{F} \\ \color{navy}{F} & T & \color{navy}{F} & T & T & \color{navy}{F} \\ \color{navy}{F} & \color{navy}{F} & T & T & T & \color{navy}{F} \\ \color{navy}{F} & \color{navy}{F} & \color{navy}{F} & T & T & \color{navy}{F}\end{array}$$

Comment: okay, so using this I could say $(P,Q,R) = (T, T, T), (T, T, F), (T, F, T) $ or $(F, F, F)$? I this correct, or are there more that I am missing?

Comment: @BenKnoll I've added a truth tableau.  $P\to(Q\vee R)$ is falsified only by $(P,Q,R)=(T, F, F)$ .  All other truth assignments are valid.

Answer (score 0):

**Terminology**

- $\implies$ means "implies"
- $\vee$ means "or" (logic)

"$P\implies{Q}\vee{R}$" essentially means that if $P$ is true, then either $Q$ or $R$ is true. So $Q$ could be true and $R$ could be false. And vice-versa. And if $P$ is false, then either $Q$ or $R$ is false.